# Get start date and end date of month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I want to get start and end date of month in `ruby on rails`. User enter integer value from 1..12.
If user enter 1 then `JAN` start_date,end_date
If user enter 2 then `FEB` start_date,end_date
If user enter 3 then `MARCH` start_date,end_date
and so on

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are built-in methods in active_support (part of Rails):

```
month_number = 5 # user-provided month number
month_beginning = Date.new(Date.today.year, month_number)
# => Sun, 01 May 2016
month_ending = month_beginning.end_of_month
# => Tue, 31 May 2016
```

Comment: i WATN THAT IF USER enter 1 then jan , if 2 then feb  start date end  date etc

Comment: Well then edit your question to be more understandable. And please don't use caps-lock.

Comment: Ok, but what about the year? We can't have date without year number, on the other hand, the user enters only month number.

Comment: it by default current year

Comment: any other solution of that?